# Unquoting without eval

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp, eval

I store some macros in quoted form (because in fact they produce lambdas with tricky lexical environment and I prefer store and serialize them as lists). So now I'm trying:

```
(defun play (s)
  (funcall (macroexpand s)))
```

Macroexpand evaluates quoted lambda, so funcall can't run it. How to unquote result of `macroexpand` without `eval`? Because in my case it would cause indefensible security hole.

MORE INFO:

What I get look like this (in simplest case):

> FUNCALL: #1=#'(LAMBDA (#:G6008) (SYMBOL-MACROLET NIL T)) is not a function name; try using a symbol instead

and `symbol-macrolet` is what actually builds up "tricky lexical environment" *inside* lambda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Macroexpand evaluates quoted lambda, so funcall can't run it. How to
>   unquote result of macroexpand without eval? Because in my case it
>   would cause indefensible security hole.

I think that Sylwester's comment about the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) is probably right here;   it sounds like you're trying to do something that might be done better in a different way.  That said, if you have a list that's a lambda expression, you can use `coerce` to get a function object instead of using `eval`.  That is, you can do this:

```lisp
CL-USER> (funcall '(lambda () 42))
; Error, like you've been having

CL-USER> (funcall (coerce '(lambda () 42) 'function))
42 ; turned the list (lambda () 42) into a function and called it
```

This is described in the documentation for [`coerce`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_coerce.htm);  when the "output" type is `function`, this is what happens with the object argument:

> If the result-type is function, and object is any function name that
>   is fbound but that is globally defined neither as a macro name nor as
>   a special operator, then the result is the functional value of object.
>
> If the result-type is function, and object is a lambda expression,
>   then the result is a closure of object in the null lexical
>   environment.

Thus, if you have a function that returns list of the form `(lambda ...)`, you can use `coerce` and `funcall` with its result.  This includes macroexpansions, although you may want to use `macroexpand-1` rather than `macroexpand`, because `lambda` is already a macro, so if you expand too far, `(lambda () ...)` turns into `(function (lambda () ...))`.

```
CL-USER> (defmacro my-constantly (value)
           `(lambda () ,value))
MY-CONSTANTLY
CL-USER> (macroexpand-1 '(my-constantly 36))
(LAMBDA () 36)
T
CL-USER> (funcall (coerce (macroexpand-1 '(my-constantly 36)) 'function))
36
```

If you try that with the plain `macroexpand`, though, there's a problem.  Consider yourself warned:

```
CL-USER> (macroexpand '(my-constantly 36))
#'(LAMBDA () 36) ; not a list, but a function
T
CL-USER> (funcall (coerce (macroexpand '(my-constantly 36)) 'function))
; Error. :(
```

Comment: Wow.. I'm speechless. It even does lexical free variables.

Comment: @Sylwester I added citation from the HyperSpec;  it creates a lexical closure in the null lexical environment (the global environment).  But it should be safer than `eval`, because it's only going to get applied to lambda-expressions, not arbitrary forms.

Comment: Then CLISP is off spec. I did this `(defparameter x 10) (let ((x 5))  (funcall (coerce '(lambda (y) (+ x y)) 'function) x)) ; ==> 10` if the function was evaluated in the null-environment I'd expect 15.

Comment: @Sylwester It doesn't do lexical variables.  CLISP isn't off spec.  Since you defined `x` with `defparameter`, you declared `x` special globally.  That means that `(let ((x 5)) ...` is a dynamic binding of `x`.  That the function is in the null lexical environment means that the reference to x is a reference to the defparametered `x`, and at the time that you're *calling* the function, that defparametered x is bound to 5.  If you return that function outside the let and call it again with, you'll get a value that reflects the other binding of `x`.

Comment: Of course. Ear muffs makes sure this never happens irl. I tried it again with `setq` and got the expected `15` so indeed dynamic binding fooled me :)

Comment: @Sylwester Well, the results of a top-level `(setq …)` are undefined anyhow, so doing `(setq x 10)` at the top-level on an undefined variable is unpredictable, too.  Some implementations will treat it as a global special, others may do something different.

Comment: Thats fine. I wasnt aiming at portability, but Im truely amazed cl doesn't have lexical globals.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with this. First I think this is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) so if you show more of your problem I guess we might find a solution for it.

It has nothing with unquoting since when evaluation a quoted expression it's not longer quoted, but it's turn into data representation of the original quoted expression. You must eval data if you want to run it.

With `eval` you won't get the current lexical scope. So since you mention `eval` and lexical environment in the same post makes me thing you won't get what you want.

Now it's no problem making a list of functions, like this:

```
(list (lambda (x) (+ x x))
```

This is not quoted since I use `list` and teh lambda is evaluated to a closure. If it was assigned to variable x you could call it with `(funcall (car x) 10)) ; ==> 20`

**EDIT**
I actually made the same error message with this code:

```
(defmacro test () '#'(lambda (x) x))
(macroexpand '(test))             ; ==> #'(lambda (x) x) ; t
(funcall (macroexpand '(test)) 5) ; ==>
*** - funcall: #'(lambda (x) x) is not a function name; try using a symbol
      instead
```

It doesn't work since you cannot call a lambda unevaluated. You need to call the closure (function) which is the result of the evaluation of the lambda form. If you would instead not quote it you'll have that evaluation in the macro:

```
(defmacro test () #'(lambda (x) x))
(macroexpand '(test))             ; ==> #<function :lambda (x) x> ;
(funcall (macroexpand '(test)) 5) ; ==> 5
```

Actually I cannot see why you would need to make this a macro. Lets make it a function instead.

```
(defun test () #'(lambda (x) x))
(funcall (test) 5 ) ; ==> 5
```

Even if this was more comples in most cases you would do with a closure.

Comment: I need macro, because it builds contents of lambda according to its arguments. The idea is about creating scripts that affect states of complex system (which includes many objects with unique ids, etc.) and thus the scripts have access to some values in very elegant fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a case where you will find that the REPL is your friend.  To get you started:

```
cl-user> (defmacro foo () #'(lambda () :hi))
foo
cl-user> (foo)
#<Compiled-function (:internal foo) (Non-Global)  #x3020014F82FF>
cl-user> (funcall *)
:hi
cl-user> (macroexpand '(foo))
#<Compiled-function (:internal foo) (Non-Global)  #x3020014F82FF>
t
cl-user> (funcall *)
:hi
cl-user>
```

I'll note in passing that the lambda form that appears in your example takes an argument, while your funcall doesn't provide one.

Comment: Yes, you're right about argument! It's because the example is simplified for posting, and the macro I've created can produce complex things. I think it doesn't matter how many arguments it takes.